# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in some specific Android devices

Tags: java, android, exception, android-listview, indexoutofboundsexception

I have just released an application in Google Play. In an activity I am filling a list and it works in many different devices including my device Motorola Moto G. But today my friend who uses LG G3 told me that it crashes at certain point when he scrolls down. That happened some other specific devices also.

This error occurs everytime when he scrolls and at same point of list. So I assume it is not memory error. I want to underline that it does not happen in my device. Below you can find my code:

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_programim_item, null, true);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.programim_item_name);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.programim_item_img);

    // Don't use web but getItem call on the adapter itself
    txtTitle.setText(getItem(position));
    txtTitle.setTypeface(font);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]); //CRASHES HERE ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    return rowView;
}
```

I am populating imageId from a text file.

```
    public void setHareketler() {
    AssetManager am = getAssets();
    InputStreamReader ims = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String data = "File not available!";
    try {
        ims = new InputStreamReader(am.open(hareketTipi + ".txt"), "UTF-8");
        reader = new BufferedReader(ims);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (ims != null) {
        try {
            String mLine = reader.readLine();
            data = "";
            while (mLine != null) {
                data += mLine;

                // mLine bossa dur
                if (mLine == null)
                    break;

                arrHareketIsimleri.add(mLine); // hareket isimleri eklendi

                // buradan itibaren hareket resimleri eklenmesi icin
                mLine = mLine.replace(" ", "_");
                mLine = mLine.replace("-", "_");
                mLine = mLine.replace("(", "");
                mLine = mLine.replace(")", "");
                mLine = mLine.toLowerCase();
                mLine = "_" + mLine + "_thumb";
                try {
                    Class res = R.drawable.class;
                    //mLine = "_6_inch_leg_lifts"; // bu kaldirilacak
                    Field field = res.getField(mLine);
                    int drawableId = field.getInt(null);
                    arrHareketResimleri.add(drawableId); // hareket
                                                            // resimleri
                                                            // ekleniyor
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("MyTag", "Failure to get drawable id.", e);
                }
                mLine = reader.readLine();

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/programim_item_img"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/programim_item_name"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/programim_item_img"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/programim_right_arrow"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    android:textColor="@color/dark_gray" 
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/programim_right_arrow"
    android:src="@drawable/right_arrow"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

and I am attaching screenshots of the crash log. I am wondering what may cause this crash in different devices. [image][image]

Comment: can you post the content of your imageId

Comment: sorry but I couldnt understand what do u mean by content? it is defined as private final Integer[] imageId;

Comment: Make sure that your adapter getCount() function has the same value as your imageId.length

Comment: How do you populate imageId ?

Comment: @zozelfelfo it works in my device properly. I think these two values are same.

Comment: For length 44 then max index should be 43 ...

Comment: @NadirB I am populating imageIds from a txt file. I ve added my code.

Comment: so it is dynamically populated or once for all

Comment: once for all. I set all imageIds in an array once and send it to the crashing function.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that (with the given information) that when you reach the end of your listview, you face this issue. I do not think is device-related but it seems that this error is not always triggering itself.

My recommendations:

Make sure that the length of your array `imageId` has the same size as your `ListView`. Use the `getCount()` method in your adapter for that. It seems your listView is trying to get the item number 45 (position 44, as it starts from 0) and your array length is 44.

If it is a bug, what I do not think so and you do not find any other solutions, try to ignore those rows as follows.

```
if(position < imageId.length)
{
   txtTitle.setText(getItem(position));
   txtTitle.setTypeface(font);
   imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
}
```

This way you will get empty rows, but it may help you find your problem

Hope it helps

Comment: There are 4 different lists and in every list it crashes in some certain position and non of them is the end of list. So I am assuming its not reaching the end of list

Comment: maybe you are getting other errors in your other listviews, the trace you posted is for getting an element beyond the limit of your array

Comment: Hmmm but I have 51 items in that list.

Comment: and your imageId array has 51 elements aswell?

Comment: yes in my device it works and fills 51 images. it crashes at 45 in some devices. this is the problemm I guess.

Answer (score 0):

From your stack trace, I guess you are repopulating your view but your number of positions available for *imageId[]* is limited.

Try something like this,

```
  public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        View rowView;
        if(view==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_programim_item, null, true);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.programim_item_name);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.programim_item_img);

        txtTitle.setText(getItem(position));
        txtTitle.setTypeface(font);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
        }else{
           rowView=(View)view;
        }
       return rowView;
    }
```

EDIT:
If you return the maximum size of *imageId[]* (i.e say *imageId[]* has 55 images you should be returning 55 ) in this method that you override, you will dispaly all the images.
If *imageId[]* is a array list *imageId.size()* will do.

```
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return imageId[]'s size; //e.g return 55 if you have 55 images
        }
```

Comment: But I am wondering why it works in specific devices and not in other devices. If I set like this then it will not show some necessary rows in some devices. right?